# How to put RTF/HTML into Excel cell using OpenXML in C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have a need to take HTML from a rich text editor and put it into an excel sheet. The requirement is that the html is rendered and looks the same as what it does in the rich text editor.

We use OpenXML for our Excel needs but I can't seem to find a way to put HTML into a cell. I can set the value but that just displays the string.

For example, I need this HTML to render in a cell:

```
<p style="text-align: center"><strong>This is a test!</strong></p><p><s>a</s></p><p><br></p><p><u style="color: rgb(32, 43, 250)">test</u></p><ul><li>test<ul><li><span style="background-color: rgb(156, 224, 29)">test</span></li></ul></li></ul><p><br></p><p><em style="font-size: 24pt; font-family: &quot;Lucida Console&quot;">d</em></p>
```

Is there a way to do this or am I searching for something that can't be done?

Comment: I'd be really surprised if you can convince Excel to somehow render HTML into a cell.  From within the UI, you can create a string (that may contain line ends) and that may contain multiple character formats (for example, some words bolded, others in different colors, others with larger text).  That's all you can do from the Excel UI.  If you do that, and open the sheet with the `OpenXML Productivity Tool` (which you should download), you'll see that a cell like that gets its content saved as shared string consisting of Word-style "runs", each with a different format.

Comment: The Excel part of the Open XML SDK has no equivalent to the WordProcessing `altChunk` - IOW there's no built-in way to convert HTML (or other content) to Excel Open XML. You'd need to write your own conversion.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted in the comments, you will have to write your own transformation to transform HTML markup into SpreadsheetML markup. For example, let's look at the following text.

This is **bold** and *italic* text.

The HTML representation of the above sample text is pretty straightforward:

```html
<p>This is <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic</em> text.</p>
```

You need to turn the above HTML markup into the following SpreadsheetML markup (one `si` element, to be precise):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<sst xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" count="1" uniqueCount="1">
  <si>
    <r>
      <t xml:space="preserve">This is </t>
    </r>
    <r>
      <rPr>
        <b/>
        <sz val="11"/>
        <color theme="1"/>
        <rFont val="Calibri"/>
        <family val="2"/>
        <scheme val="minor"/>
      </rPr>
      <t>bold</t>
    </r>
    <r>
      <rPr>
        <sz val="11"/>
        <color theme="1"/>
        <rFont val="Calibri"/>
        <family val="2"/>
        <scheme val="minor"/>
      </rPr>
      <t xml:space="preserve"> and </t>
    </r>
    <r>
      <rPr>
        <i/>
        <sz val="11"/>
        <color theme="1"/>
        <rFont val="Calibri"/>
        <family val="2"/>
        <scheme val="minor"/>
      </rPr>
      <t>italic</t>
    </r>
    <r>
      <rPr>
        <sz val="11"/>
        <color theme="1"/>
        <rFont val="Calibri"/>
        <family val="2"/>
        <scheme val="minor"/>
      </rPr>
      <t xml:space="preserve"> text.</t>
    </r>
  </si>
</sst>
```

To do this, you really need to understand the SpreadsheetML markup and specifically the
[Shared String Table](http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/s-sml-sharedStringTable.xsd.html) (`sst` element), which is where you would render your transformed markup (as one or more `si` elements).

The transformation is best implemented as a pure functional transformation. Have a look at the [XmlTransformationTests](https://github.com/ThomasBarnekow/CodeSnippets/blob/master/CodeSnippets.Tests/OpenXml/Wordprocessing/XmlTransformationTests.Paragraph.cs) class for an example that does something similar. It transforms HTML-like XML into WordprocessingML.